# covariant derivative complex manifold

Tags: complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, smooth-manifolds, tag-removed, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Assume we have $X$ a complex manifold and $Y = Y^{\alpha} \frac{\partial}{\partial z^{\alpha}}$ and $Z = Z^{\alpha} \frac{\partial}{\partial z^{\alpha}}$ two vector fields on $X$. Let $\nabla$ be the covariant derivative. What is the computation of $\nabla_{Z}Y$ (i.e. what is $\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial z^{\beta}}}\frac{\partial}{\partial z^{\alpha}}$, i think its $0$ but why ?)?

Comment: You don't have a Levi-Civita covariant derivative unless you also impose a Riemannian metric. It does not come for free on a complex manifold. Your question has nothing to do with complex manifolds at all. The answer is in absolutely any text on Riemannian geometry.

Comment: The again perhaps the OP does not mean the Levi-Civita connection, but only a complex connection: one relative to which the complex structure is parallel.

Comment: ok sorry the without levi civita. but does it mean that: for some complex connection one has $\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial z^{\beta}}}\frac{\partial}{\partial z^{alpha}} = 0$ ? du you know some literature where i can find this ?

Comment: No. If $z^{\alpha}$ and $z^{\beta}$ are local *holomorphic* coordinates on the manifold, as I assume you mean, then you can choose a connection such that *in that single coordinate chart*, this condition holds, but you *cannot* always ensure this holds in every single coordinate chart. Because if it did, this would be a "flat" connection, and not all complex manifolds admit flat connections.

Comment: is there any literature where i can read about this ?

Comment: Any of the three following references should give you enough background to work this out, though the answer to your question may not be spelled out in detail: [1] "Complex differential geometry" by F. Zheng, [2] "Lectures on Kahler geometry" by A. Moroianu, [3] "Complex analytic and differential geometry" by J-P. Demailly (http://tinyurl.com/2dcnycm).

Comment: Any book about connections on vector bundles will discuss flat connections and obstructions to their existence. Check out Kobayashi-Nomizu, for example. It's also probably in Griffiths-Harris.